# Библиотека Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Зачем использовать библиотеку Retrofit ? Что даст использование ее, кроме как удобства для программиста в плане работа с RESTful API и в целом запросов на сервер? Она быстрее или может меньше трафика расходует ?

З.Ы. Сам использую ее везде, ибо удобно)

Comment: Затем, что она упрощает разработку.

Comment: @Suvitruf, так и есть. С ней легче делать коллбеки и прочее. Но что кроме этого она дает ? Есть какой-то прирост в производительности ?

Comment: Там кеши и т.п. Так что да, быстрее в целом, чем `AsyncTask`

Comment: Там еще используется HttpOk и он лечше чем простой HttpClient

Comment: @Saidolim при условии, что `OkHttp` сам использует `httpclient`?